# ARIMA fits well but returns "Nan" in prediction

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I used the auto_arima to get my arima's parameters, so all is good until here and the model fits very well with the data. given that my data don't have any seasonality and no trends

The problem is that when I pass to the prediction I get `NaN`s.